# How to move filing structure from our magento web server to windows

Tags: magento-1.9, media, wamp

I had a problem earlier where my images on local installation werent showing up. I found out that the problem was filing structure of our magento site. Its filing structure is case sensitive. When I copied all media over to localhost on wamp in www folder it got rid of A folder but kept a. It happened with other letters as well. Does anyone know how to get around this problem at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get rid of it. Windows/Microsoft does't know any case-sensitive file system afaik, so somewhow you have to merge them.
unix question, which should answer your problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94429/merging-folders-with-practically-the-same-name-but-different-casing